# Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger in my System

Tags: mysql

insert into attendance values(5,5,1,1,'c','2020-08-28','2019-08-28')

Can't update table 'attendance' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

I want to change attendance result to 's' When enrered row value in attendance table. So I want this trigger to automatically do this for me everytime a row is entered.

create table attendance(stu_id          int                 not null,
                        g_id            int                 not null,
                        school_id       int                 not null,
                        rno             int                 not null,
                        result          enum('s','f','c')   not null,
                        to_date         date                not null,
                        from_date       date                not null,
                        primary key(stu_id,g_id,school_id,rno),
foreign key(stu_id)      references student(id),
foreign key(g_id)        references grade(id),
foreign key(school_id)   references school(id));

delimiter $
create trigger trig_student_att_insert before insert on attendance
for each row
begin

update attendance set result='s' where result='c' and  g_id!=new.g_id and stu_id=new.stu_id;

end $
delimiter;

Comment: did you found any solution ?